# Pervasive error 161 after login

Tags: windows

Upon launching our program called *Switch*, which is unfortunately no longer supported by our vendor we get the following error message:

[image: error3012]

After I reinstall perviasive I get the following error message:
[image: error161]

Error 161 usually means that you have no licenses left to use, however this is not the case as you can login to our program, and start a few tasks, however making any changes to DB is when the error pops up.

Any help with this error would be great as Google is only giving the no licenses error.

Comment: Just from a brief Google search, it appears that you need to do a lot more work to rule out license issues (and state in your question what you have done). Also you are probably well aware that your company should have gotten rid of this rubbish years ago.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be the very epitome of too localized.

Comment: I understand it is very localised in terms of program, however opened up by how pervasive can be used for many different applications. We're replacing this with HMS in the next few months, we just need it to last a bit longer. I've been told that the volume of licences we have out weigh the volume we have not being able to access, furthermore this error would normally come up when starting the program, not during the use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows error code 161 is [ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME](https://serverfault.com/questions/576352/pervasive-error-161-after-login). If I had to guess, I'd say that you're having a permissions problem with the user running the application not having rights to write to the `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` folder.

I find [a quasi-related question on another site](http://cs.pervasive.com/forums/t/13572.aspx) that lends my theory some credence, at least.